# sinon-as-promised not returning correct?

Tags: javascript, promise, bdd, sinon

I'm wondering why the two methods below are returning different things. I was expecting both to return a resolved promise with the string value ''.

Using `sinon` module:

```
sinon.stub(db, 'query').returns(Promise.resolve('<VALUE>'));
console.log(db.query()); 
// echos: Promise { '<VALUE>' }
```

And then using `sinon-as-promised` module:

```
sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves('<VALUE>');
console.log(db.query());
/* echos: 
    { then: [Function: then],
      catch: [Function],
      finally: [Function] }
*/
```

I must be reading the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised) in relation to `stub.resolves(value)` states that:

> When called, the stub will return a "thenable" object which will
>   return a promise for the provided value.

You are logging the "thenable" object to the console, not the `Promise` returned by this "thenable" object. You can log the value by doing this:

```
sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves('<VALUE>').then(function(value){
    console.log(value); // <VALUE>
});
```

You can alternatively log the returned `Promise` by doing this:

```
var promise = sinon.stub(db, 'query').resolves('<VALUE>').then(function({
});

console.log(promise);
```

Comment: how does this work? it keeps telling me that resolves is not a function